# couchbase spatial queries with large geometries

Tags: javascript, couchbase

I am using Couchbase 3.0.2 to store GeoJSON documents. I have defined a very simple spatial view:

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.geometry) {
        emit(doc.geometry, null);
    }
}
```

The query:

```
http://localhost:8092/feature/_design/dev_foo/_spatial/bar?bbox=-180%2C-90%2C180%2C90&stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&full_set=true
```

works fine until I add a document with a very large geometry, e.g. with 10,000 points:

```
{"id": "1234",
 "geometry": {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[145,-38],[145.1,-38.1], ...10,000 more ... ]]}}
```

I receive the error:

```
{"error":"error","reason":"{index_builder_exit,139,<<>>}"}
```

Is there a documented upper limit on the size of the geometry that can be indexed for spatial views?

Are there any workarounds for getting Couchbase to handle these large geometries - or at least ignore them and not fail completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excellent developers at Couchbase have confirmed it is a bug with using large geometries as the emitted key, and will be fixed in the next release (i.e. after 3.0.3).

see https://forums.couchbase.com/t/spatial-views-and-geometry-size-limits/3465

Their suggested workaround in the meantime is to calculate and emit the bounding box rather than the entire geometry.